# Recursive functional dependency not working

Tags: haskell, ghc, functional-dependencies

I'm trying to multiply array of units (from `dimensional`) in a phantom type and I'm having trouble with functional dependencies. A simplified version of the problem is the following :

I have the following type

```
data F (a:: [*]) = F String
```

Where the string represent an expression in a foreign language and a phantom type representing a list of types.

I can do things like

```
x = F "x" :: F '[Double]
y = F "(1,3)" :: F '[Int, Int]
```

I managed to implements arithmetics operators like this by creating a `Nums` class which is a list of `Num`.

```
class Nums (a::[*])
instance Nums '[]
instance (Num a, Nums as) => Num (a ': as)
```

Then I can do instanciate `Num F`

```
instance Nums as => F as where
   (F a) * (F b) = F (a ++ "*" ++ b)
   ... etc ...
```

Now, I'm trying to do the same using physical units. I can do it with a list of one type this way

```
import qualified Numeric.Units.Dimensional as Dim

data F (a::[*]) = F String
(!*!) :: (Num n, Dim.Mul a b c) => F '[Dim.Dimensional v a n]
                                -> F '[Dim.Dimensional v b n]
                                -> F '[Dim.Dimensional v c n]

(F a) !*! (F b) = F (a ++ "*" ++ b)
```

That's seem to work, I can "multiply" 2 'F's of different units, and the result is in the corret unit.
Obviously, I want to generalize this to any list and use the same tricks as `Nums` which I call `Muls`.

```
class Muls a b c | a b -> c
instance '[] '[] '[]
instance (Num n, Mul a b c, Muls as bs cs) 
   => Muls (Dim.Dimensional v a n ': as)
           (Dim.Dimensional v b n ': bs)
           (Dim.Dimensional v c n ': cs)

!*! :: (Muls as bs cs) => F as -> F bs -> F cs
(F a) !*! (F b) = F (a ++ "*" ++ b)
```

I got an `Illegal Instance declaration` error :

```
Illegal instance declaration for
 ‘Muls
    (Dim.Dimensional v a n : as)
    (Dim.Dimensional v b n : bs)
    (Dim.Dimensional v c n : cs)’
 The coverage condition fails in class ‘Muls’
   for functional dependency: ‘a b -> c’
 Reason: lhs types ‘Dim.Dimensional v a n : as’, ‘Dim.Dimensional
                                                    v b n
                                                    : bs’
   do not jointly determine rhs type ‘Dim.Dimensional v c n : cs’
 Using UndecidableInstances might help
In the instance declaration for
 ‘Muls (Dim.Dimensional v a n : as) (Dim.Dimensional v b n
                                    : bs) (Dim.Dimensional v c n : cs)’
```

If I use the `UndecidableInstances` extension, it seems to work indeed. My question, is why do I need this extension and is there a way I could avoid it ?

Alternatively, I probably could get this working using the type family version of `dimensional`. Unfortunatly, I need custom units and it's not clear if `dimensional-tf` supports user defined units.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

By default Haskell requires that instance selection be decidable, ie, that an attempt to decide if an type satisfy a constraint cannot cause an infinite loop in the compiler. Consider the following code:

```
class A (a :: *)
class B (a :: *) 
instance A a => B a
```

This obviously instance *could* cause an infinite loop (it won't do so necessarily!). Even if every other instance by itself can't cause an infinite loop, the addition of this instance can. There is probably a rigorous proof of this somewhere but I don't know it.

The only thing `UndecidableInstances` does is say "I promise I will never call my functions with types which cause infinite loops, so even though my instances can produce infinite loops, I accept responsibility for making sure that doesn't happen."

On the other hand, instances of the form:

```
instance (C1 a1, C2 a2 ... Cn an) => C (T a1 a2 .. an)
```

Will never produce an infinite loop, since Haskell doesn't allow infinite types, and this instance unpacks a single constructor, so even if `Ci` refers back to `C` you will eventually get to a type constructor which has 0 type parameters.

If you write an instance which is not decidable, you *should* get

```
test.hs:26:10:
    Constraint is no smaller than the instance head
      in the constraint: A a
    (Use UndecidableInstances to permit this)
    In the instance declaration for `B a'
```

I think this is the error you should see in your case and that displaying the error you actually see should be considered a bug.

Comment: Why is it "obvious" that it can cause an infinite loop ?

Comment: @mb14 Would you agree that the proof that `instance C a => C a` can produce an infinite loop is trivial? The same principle is at work in the above case. Since the universe of type class instances is open, the constraint `A a` in `instance A a => B a` *could* end up containing a `B a` once it was expanded. So `A a` could be equal to something like `C1 a, C2 a, .. Cn a, B a`. This would make the instance reduce to `instance (C1 a, C2 a, .. Cn a, B a) => B a`, which is trivially overlapping.

Comment: Ok, or  I suppose I could have also `instance B a => A a`.