# Why does this violate the "Coverage Condition"

Tags: haskell

Reading about `UndecidableInstances` I understand that the my problem in [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/q/25432290/376113) is equivalent to:

```
class Convert a b | a -> b where
     convert :: a -> b

instance Convert a b => Convert [a] [b] where
     convert = map convert
```

I understand why the 'UndecidableInstance' is necessary and (kind of) why the type checker can loop in certain case. However, I still don't understand how it violates the 'Coverage Condition'. I mean, when I read the definition

> For each functional dependency, `tvsleft -> tvsright`, of the class, every type variable in 
>   `S(tvsright)` must appear in `S(tvsleft)`, where `S` is the substitution mapping each type 
>   variable in the class declaration to the corresponding type in the instance declaration.

The previous example seems to satisfy this definition. I know it doesn't but I can't see why (I probably doesn't really understand it).

Answer (score 3):

I'm guessing like me you first thought `tvsleft` had something to do with the part to the left of the `=>` in the instance.  But after reading more carefully, I see it doesn't.  At least for this example, this is a restriction on the instance *head* only.

For the class with head `Convert a b` and functional dependency `a -> b` we have

```
tvsleft = a
tvsright = b
```

For the instance we must then substitute the variables in the class head `Convert a b` to get the instance head `Convert [a] [b]`, giving

```
S(tvsleft) = S(a) = [a]
S(tvsright) = S(b) = [b]
```

and the type variable `b` in `[b]` does not occur in `[a]`.

Comment: I got it, It's like writting `instance Convert a b`, then. My mistake is the I see `instance Convert a b => Convert [a] [b]` as Convert [a] [f a]` with `f a` such as `Convert a (f a)` or `f ~ Convert-1`. The mistake is `f` doesn't exist which is weird.